# Replacing items in nested list that contain same answer

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a nested list that looks like this:

```
data = [
['student 1', '"answer 0"', '"answer 2"', '"answer 2"', '"answer 0"'],
['student 2', '"answer 4"', '"answer 2"', '"answer 4"', '"answer 0"']]
```

I want the results to appear as:

```
data = [
['student 1', 'Blue', 'Up', 'Left', 'Football'],
['student 2', 'Red', 'Up', 'Right', 'Football']]
```

Depending on the index in the list, it can have a different result, but in the data it can contain the same string.  What is an efficient way to accomplish this task?

Comment: "_but in the data it can contain the same string..._" meaning?

Comment: What is the inefficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: I do not understand the logic of how your example input would get turned into your desired output.

Comment: You need to provide more information about how to data for each student is store. Or are you just wanting to strip the inner double quotations from the answers in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple `[index, answer, replacement]` replacement map, like:

```
replacement_map = {
    1: {'"answer 0"': "Blue",  # replacements for index 1
        '"answer 1"': "Green",
        '"answer 2"': "Yellow",
        '"answer 3"': "Purple",
        '"answer 4"': "Red"},
    2: {'"answer 0"': "Right",  # replacements for index 2
        '"answer 1"': "Left",
        '"answer 2"': "Up",
        '"answer 4"': "Down"},
    3: {'"answer 0"': "Up",  # replacements for index 3
        '"answer 1"': "Down",
        '"answer 2"': "Left",
        '"answer 4"': "Right"},
    4: {'"answer 0"': "Football",  # replacements for index 4
        '"answer 1"': "Pocket billiard"}
}

data = [
    ['student 1', '"answer 0"', '"answer 2"', '"answer 2"', '"answer 0"'],
    ['student 2', '"answer 4"', '"answer 2"', '"answer 4"', '"answer 0"']
]

replaced_data = []  # we'll store our data here
for element in data:
    replaced_element = []
    for index, item in enumerate(element):
        if index in replacement_map:
            replaced_element.append(replacement_map[index].get(item, item))
        else:  # no replacement available for this index
            replaced_element.append(item)
    replaced_data.append(replaced_element)
# replaced_data contains:
# [['student 1', 'Blue', 'Up', 'Left', 'Football'],
#  ['student 2', 'Red', 'Up', 'Right', 'Football']]
```

If you really want it as efficient as possible, you can do it through list comprehension:

```
replaced_data = [[replacement_map.get(index, {}).get(item, item) for index, item in enumerate(element)] for element in data]
```

But that won't give you much of a speed up (in fact, in dependence on the replacement map it might end up slower) and is horrible to read.